# What can I use to clean gas range burners?

Tags: cleaning

I moved to a new house and the cook stove looks dirty and rusted. What's the best product or procedure to clean this without damaging it? It's a Viking stove.

[image: burners picture]

Answer (score 3):

The cast iron will clean up with a heavy-duty wire brush. You can get them in all sizes down to toothbrush size. You can't rescue the pitted areas, but you can get rid of the rust & they will shine up a bit.
*From comments* - you can treat it like a cast-iron skillet or wok & bake on layers of polymerised cooking oil in the oven, which will prevent further rusting.

The aluminium rings with regular oven cleaner. Remove them & drop in a plastic bag with plenty of cleaning product. Seal to prevent evaporation. Leave overnight. Rinse, repeat if necessary.
It may discolour the surface [they tend to go matt white/light grey] but you can shine that back up with either a soft wire brush or melamine block.

The enamel looks like it's been damaged. Oven cleaner would clean it, but may also cause more damage to the exposed metals. Because of the damage I wouldn't use anything stronger than regular kitchen cleaner, Barkeeper's Friend &/or a melamine block.
You can get high temperature paints which may help re-coat this, but I've never used them so I have no recommendations - see https://www.thestovecompany.co.uk/stove-care-products/high-temperature-stove-paint for examples.

Comment: Suggestion, after cleaning the cast iron, you can treat it like cast iron cookware and season it with a light coat of oil and cooking in the oven. It greatly prevents surface rusting that might occur after cleaning.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions

Comment: electrolysis is a great way to restore cast iron; it eats away the rust but not the plain iron. all you need is a car battery or 12v supply, water, and baking soda. Watch some youtubes on it...